# Bash command to list names of specific directories and subdirectories on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, sh

I need a bash command that searches the directory "rawdata" for all subdirectories with names starting with "AB", searches all these for the subdirectory "demo" and within all "demo" directories all subdirectories with a name consisting of just numbers. From all these I need the name of the file that has ".txt" as an extension. The command always has to look just one depth and not search deeper... I tried to write all the found filenames in "test.txt" but my code didn't work right.

My approach:

```
find rawdata/AB* -type d -name 'demo' -exec find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]+' -exec find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" {} \; | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' > test.txt
```

I got error messages like this:

```
‘rawdata/AB.../q.../A.../demultiplexed’: No such file or directory
```

which for me is a proof that it does not first search for demo, because it took the subdirectory q... Further on it didn't take a folder with a number as name!

A correct path should look like this: `‘rawdata/AB.../demo/123/hereAndJustInThisLevelHereIsTheSearchedFile.txt’`
So on every first directory level there must be the order "rawdata", on the second level it should just check the directories whose names start with "AB", in the third level there is just one "demo" and it should check just this and in the fourth level it must check just all directories that have a number as folder name!

I already tried some other similar code versions but none of them gave me the right result.

Comment: I'm not a 100% certain I get what you're after, and your approach seems very complicated ... would this do the `find` aspect of your question? ` find -regex './rawdata/.*/demo/[0-9]+/.*\.txt'`

Comment: This sound like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)! Try simply:  `ls rawdata/AB*/demo/[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]}}}}/*.txt` Note: this will search for numbered directory containing 1 to 5 digits. You could add more `{,[0-9]}`  nested if needed!

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub `ls` is an external command while `printf` is a builtin and so with `ls rawdata/AB*/demo/[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]}}}}/*.txt` you need to repeat `{,[0-9]}` as many times as the max number of digits your file names can have and  if the number of generated file names * their length exceeds `ARG_MAX` it'd fail, while `printf '%s\n' rawdata/AB*/demo/+([0-9])/*.txt` will work for any number of digits without any duplicate code and will not fail even if `ARG_MAX` is exceeded so I don't know what the reason would be to use that `ls` command for this.

Comment: `ls` was (maybe a bad) sample, correct use could be: `for file in rawdata/AB*/demo/[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]}}}}/*.txt` !  `MAX_ARG` don't apply for [tag:bash] *builtin*, like `for file in ...`.

Comment: I never said `find` was a builtin, I said `printf` is a builtin. I never said `ARG_MAX` applied to a `for` loop, I said it applied to `ls`.

Comment: @EdMorton So you will agree, correct syntax could by `for file in rawdata/AB*/demo/[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]}}}}/*.txt;do ...` and using `find` here is a *wrong way*.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `find` to find files, it's what it exists to do. If you prefer writing a `for` loop, though, then go for it as there's nothing wrong with that either but I don't see any reason not to use the simpler globbing pattern that I used in the `printf` with `+([0-9])` to match any number of digits instead of having to decide how many digits your file name could have and then writing `[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{...etc...}}}}}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256291/discussion-between-f-hauri-give-up-github-and-ed-morton).

Comment: @EdMorton Ok `ls` is a wrong sample: Use *builtin*: `printf '%s\n' rawdata/AB*/demo/[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]{,[0-9]}}}}/*.txt‌​`

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I already show using `printf` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77668501/1745001) but with a briefer, simpler, and more robust (as it covers any number of digits) glob expression `printf '%s\n' rawdata/AB*/demo/+([0-9])/*.txt` so Im not sure where you're going with this but just post whatever it is you want to suggest as an answer so it's easy for everyone to find and provide feedback, you can modify it any time you like if you'd rather suggest some other command and/or describe why you think it's the right approach or state anything else you want to say about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates a possible way to do what you want with pure POSIX shell:

```
#! /bin/sh -

for txtfile in rawdata/AB*/demo/*/*.txt; do
    case $txtfile in
        rawdata/AB*/demo/*[!0-9]*/*.txt) : ;;
        *) [ -f "$txtfile" ] && printf '%s\n' "${txtfile##*/}" ;;
    esac
done
```

- See the [Pattern Matching Notation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) section of the POSIX [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) document for an explanation of the `rawdata/AB*/demo/*/*.txt` and `rawdata/AB*/demo/*[!0-9]*/*.txt` patterns.
- `rawdata/AB*/demo/*[!0-9]*/*.txt) : ;;` causes files in level 3 subdirectories that contain non-numeric characters to be skipped.
- See the [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) section of the POSIX [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) document for an explanation of `${txtfile##*/}`.
- This code works with Bash, but if it will always be run with Bash then it would be better (shorter, clearer) to use the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) feature to match numeric directory names.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub, potential issues with using `ls` like this are covered in comments on the question.  Issues with the brace expansion needing to make assumptions about maximum name lengths are also discussed.  From the point of view of my answer, I want to use only POSIX shell features so brace expansion isn't an option.  With Bash code  I think that `extglob` is a better option (shorter, and makes no assumptions about name lengths).

Answer (score 1):

> I need a bash command that searches into folder "rawdata"

```
find 'rawdata' -maxdepth 1
```

> all subfolders names starting with "AB",

```
find 'rawdata' -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'AB*'
```

> searches in all this orders the
> subfolder "demo"

```
while IFS= read -r dir1; do
    find "$dir1" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'demo'
done < <(find 'rawdata' -type d -name 'AB*')
```

> and in the "demo" folder all subfolders with a name
> consisting of just numbers.

```
while IFS= read -r dir1; do
    while IFS= read -r dir2; do
        find "$dir2" -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]+$'
    done < <(find "$dir1" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'demo')
done < <(find 'rawdata' -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'AB*')
```

> From all this folders that are named with
> a number I need the name of the file that hat ".txt" as ending.

```
while IFS= read -r dir1; do
    while IFS= read -r dir2; do
        while IFS= read -r dir3; do
            find "$dir3" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt'
        done < <(find "$dir2" -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]*$')
    done < <(find "$dir1" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'demo')
done < <(find 'rawdata' -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'AB*')
```

Alternatively you could just do:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' rawdata/AB*/demo/+([0-9])/*.txt
```

Since `printf` is a builtin that won't fail if there's a large number of files like other tools would if the combination of the number of files and length of their names exceeded `ARG_MAX`.

For example, given this directory structure:

```
$ mkdir -p rawdata/ABx/demo/17/
$ mkdir -p rawdata/ABy/demo/235
$ > rawdata/ABx/demo/17/foo.txt
$ > rawdata/ABx/demo/17/bar.txt
$ > rawdata/ABy/demo/235/whatever.txt
```

to get the full paths to the files:

```
$ while IFS= read -r dir1; do
    while IFS= read -r dir2; do
        while IFS= read -r dir3; do
            find "$dir3" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt'
        done < <(find "$dir2" -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]*$')
    done < <(find "$dir1" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'demo')
done < <(find 'rawdata' -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'AB*')
rawdata/ABx/demo/17/bar.txt
rawdata/ABx/demo/17/foo.txt
rawdata/ABy/demo/235/whatever.txt
```

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ printf '%s\n' rawdata/AB*/demo/+([0-9])/*.txt
rawdata/ABx/demo/17/bar.txt
rawdata/ABx/demo/17/foo.txt
rawdata/ABy/demo/235/whatever.txt
```

or to just get the names of the files:

```
$ while IFS= read -r dir1; do
    while IFS= read -r dir2; do
        while IFS= read -r dir3; do
            find "$dir3" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%P\n'
        done < <(find "$dir2" -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]*$')
    done < <(find "$dir1" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'demo')
done < <(find 'rawdata' -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'AB*')
bar.txt
foo.txt
whatever.txt
```

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ printf '%s\n' rawdata/AB*/demo/+([0-9])/*.txt | sed 's:.*/::'
bar.txt
foo.txt
whatever.txt
```

The above assumes that none of your file or directory names contain newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I still think that this simple `find` should do the trick.

```
find -regex './rawdata/AB.*/demo/[0-9]+/.*\.txt'|awk -F/ '{print $NF}' > test.txt
```

Comment: `.` matches `/` in `find` regex patterns, so the `find` in the answer could find unwanted paths such as `rawdata/ABx/CDy/demo/17/foo.txt`.  Replacing `.*` with `[^/]*` in the regular expression might work.